# Reverse a string by using unique pointer c++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Below are my .cpp file and .h file. After getting a lot of help from Mike, I finally get it working; however, when I compile it on Visual Studio 2012, it gives me 2 warnings about '<' signed/unsigned  mismatch right on the line "for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)". Can anyone tell me what I did wrong in there ?

```
[code]
#include"DownwardStack.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
#include<cassert>

using namespace std;

unique_ptr<string> reverse_string(string const &s);

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    string s;

    unique_ptr<string> reverse(new string());

    unique_ptr<DownwardStack<int>> ptr(new DownwardStack<int>());

    cout << "Your string: ";
    cin >> s;

    reverse = reverse_string(s);

    cout << "Your reverse string is: " << *reverse << endl;

    if(ptr->IsEmpty())
        cout << "ptr is empty" << endl;
    else
        cout << "ptr is not empty" << endl;

    assert(ptr->IsEmpty());
    assert(!ptr->IsFull());
    ptr->Push(5);
    ptr->Push(7);
    ptr->Push(10);
    ptr->Push(15);
    ptr->Push(4);

    cout << "Stack size: " << ptr->GetSize() << endl;
    cout << "Top element: " << ptr->Peek() << endl;
    cout << "Pop one element out." << endl;
    ptr->Pop();
    cout << "Top element: " << ptr->Peek() << endl;

    return 0;
}

unique_ptr<string> reverse_string(string const &s)
{
    DownwardStack<char> stack;

    cout << s.length() << endl;
    // Here it gives me a warning on the for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        stack.Push(s[i]);
    }


    unique_ptr<string> result(new string);


    // Again it gives me a warning on the for loop
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        *result += stack.Peek();
        stack.Pop();
    }

    return result;
}

[/code]
```

This is my header file .h

```
[code]
#pragma once
#include<cassert>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

// size: number of elements inside the array
const int FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY = 100;

template<class T>
class DownwardStack
{
public:
    DownwardStack();
    ~DownwardStack();
    // 1 step
    // O(0)
    int GetSize() const {return size;}
    bool IsEmpty() const {return (size==0);}
    bool IsFull() const {return (size==FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY);}
    T Peek();
    void Pop();
    void Push(T val);
    void Clear();
    void DisplayStack();
private:
    int size;
    T elements[FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY];
};

// O(1)
template<class T>
DownwardStack<T>::DownwardStack()
{
    size = 0;
}

template<class T>
DownwardStack<T>::~DownwardStack()
{
}

// assert = 1 step
// IsEmpty() = 1 step
// total = 2 steps
// f(n) = 2
// O(1)
template<class T>
T DownwardStack<T>::Peek()
{
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    return elements[FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY - size];
}

// In order to take something out, it must not be empty
// assert = 1 step
// IsEmpty() = 1 step
// size-- = 1 step
// total = 3 steps
// O(1)
template<class T>
void DownwardStack<T>::Pop()
{
    assert(!IsEmpty());
    size--;
}

// In order to put in something, the stack must not be full
// assert = 1 step
// IsFull = 1 step
// assignment = 1 step
// size++ = 1 step
// total = 4 steps
// O(1)
template<class T>
void DownwardStack<T>::Push(T val)
{
    assert(!IsFull());
    elements[FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY - size - 1] = val;
    size++;
}

template<class T>
void DownwardStack<T>::Clear()
{
    size = FIXED_ARRAYED_STACK_CAPACITY;
    assert(IsEmpty());
}



[/code]
```

Comment: Why on earth would you return a pointer to a dynamically allocated string? Just return a string by value and reduce the amount of gratuitous indirection in the world. Likewise, the stack should be a local automatic variable.

Comment: It's the homework and it's driving me crazy Mike !!!!

Comment: I'd suggest rethinking const correctness for your stack class. Also, why use a constant somewhere, when you could easily `template <typename T, std::size_t FIXED_ARRAY_CAPACITY = 100>`?

Comment: thanks nijansen, I would not know it's possible that way

Comment: @Jarod42 Homework's okay. It's the question that isn't specific enough. They need to break it down to the smallest example of the problem they're having... do the analysis themselves.

Comment: @Jarod42 That is a terrible downvote reason. You could argue that this question is not focused enough, that it does not show enough engagement to solve the problem by oneself, or a million other reasons; but downvoting simply because it is a homework question does not make sense. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) may be a valuable read.

Comment: For posting questions (or answers), the site uses Markdown. When editing, there is a ? button to help you. In other words, we don't use `<code>` blocks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been up for 6 hours straight already and I am not really paying attention to it. I'll try the ? button next time

Comment: @ PeterWood, @nijansen: ok, noted.

Comment: `s.length()` returns `size_t` which is unsigned. you may use `size_t i` to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I would implement this as

```
std::string reverse_string(std::string const & s) {
    return {s.rbegin(), s.rend()};            // C++11 or later
    return std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()); // historical dialects of C++
}
```

If you really must make life difficult for yourself by using a stack: push each character into it, then pop each out into the new string. By the nature of stacks, you'll pop the characters in the reverse order.

```
std::string reverse_string(std::string const & s) {
    DownwardStack<char> stack;

    // write a loop to push each character of "s" onto "stack"

    std::string result;

    // write a loop to pop each character from "stack" into "result"

    return result;
}
```

If you absolutely have to return a unique pointer, (which you really, really shouldn't), then that becomes

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> reverse_string(std::string const & s) {
    DownwardStack<char> stack;

    // write a loop to push each character of "s" onto "stack"

    std::unique_ptr<std::string> result(new std::string);

    // write a loop to pop each character from "stack" into "*result"

    return result;
}
```

And do the world a favour: only use `new` when you actually need it. There's no reason to use `unique_ptr` either for the stack (make that automatic), or the return value (since `std::string` is movable).

Comment: It's not that I want to do it the difficult way. It's what the professor asks me to :( But Thanks Mike

Comment: How would I solve the problem by using unique pointer Mike ? I have no clue how to do it....

Comment: @user2383193: OK, the second paragraph should give you a pointer.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more Mike ? I really don't know how to build a unique pointer function

Comment: @user2383193: OK, I've added a bit more detail. A function returning a `unique_ptr` is just like a function returning any other object type.

Comment: thanks a lot Mike. I'll try to see if it works out in my code

Comment: This is what I come up so far:
[code]
unique_ptr<string> reverse_string(string const &s)
{
 DownwardStack<char> stack;

 char *a = new char[s.size() + 1];
 a[s.size()] = 0;
 memcpy(a, s.c_str(), s.size());

 for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
 {
  stack.Push(i);
 }

 unique_ptr<string> result(new string);

 // I do not know how to capture the char that has been

 return result;
}
[/code]

Comment: @user2383193: Use `stack.peek()` to get a character from the stack. Use `*result += ch` to append a character to the result. Use `stack.pop()` to remove the character from the stack. And stop using `new` when you don't need it: there's absolutely no need to copy the string into an array. Just push `s[i]` onto the stack in the first loop. If you're still having trouble, go back and read the early chapters of your text book.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I finally got it working. But I still got warning about the '<' signed/unsigned mismatch for the loop "for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++). If I assign another variable to hold the value of s.length() and substitute it into the for loop, everything is fine, without any warnings at all. That makes me wonder, why does it complain about s.length() when it actually returns an integer ?

Comment: @user2383193: Use `size_t`, not `int`, as an index. It's unsigned (as an index should be), and guaranteed large enough for any normal string.